# Extracting data from a xml file into a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, xml, pandas, dataframe, data-extraction

I'm trying to extract some data from a xml file, here's a sample from the file (it's quite big).

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<revista numero="2558" data="14/01/2020">
  <processo numero="909359539" data-deposito="11/05/2015" data-concessao="14/01/2020" data-vigencia="14/01/2030">
    <despachos>
      <despacho codigo="IPAS158" nome="Concessão de registro"/>
    </despachos>
    <titulares>
      <titular nome-razao-social="DISTRIBUIDORA DE SUPERGELADOS REGIONAIS LTDA" pais="BR" uf="SP"/>
    </titulares>
    <marca apresentacao="Mista" natureza="De Serviço">
      <nome>DSR DISTRIBUIDORA DE SUPERGELADOS REGIONAIS</nome>
    </marca>
    <classes-vienna edicao="4">
      <classe-vienna codigo="24.1.15"/>
      <classe-vienna codigo="27.5.1"/>
    </classes-vienna>
    <lista-classe-nice>
      <classe-nice codigo="35">
        <especificacao>Administração de negócios, comercialização através de qualquer meio de produtos alimentícios, em especial, picolé, sorvetes, gelados comestíveis, sobremesas congeladas; franchising; representação comercial; serviços de distribuição, representação, importação e exportação de produtos alimentícios, em especial, picolé, sorvetes, gelados comestíveis, sobremesas congeladas; assessoria em gestão comercial ou industrial.; </especificacao>
        <status>Deferido</status>
      </classe-nice>
    </lista-classe-nice>
    <procurador>Vaz e Dias Advogados &amp; Associados</procurador>
  </processo>
  <processo numero="826455069" data-deposito="12/03/2004" data-concessao="14/01/2020" data-vigencia="14/01/2030">
    <despachos>
      <despacho codigo="IPAS158" nome="Concessão de registro"/>
    </despachos>
    <titulares>
      <titular nome-razao-social="ESCOLA CASINHA BRANCA DE UBERLÂNDIA LTDA-ME" pais="BR" uf="MG"/>
    </titulares>
    <marca apresentacao="Mista" natureza="De Serviço">
      <nome>CASINHA BRANCA</nome>
    </marca>
    <classes-vienna edicao="4">
      <classe-vienna codigo="7.1.8"/>
      <classe-vienna codigo="27.5.1"/>
    </classes-vienna>
    <lista-classe-nice>
      <classe-nice codigo="41">
        <especificacao>escola maternal, jardim e pré escola (ensino infantil).; </especificacao>
        <status>Deferido</status>
      </classe-nice>
    </lista-classe-nice>
    <procurador>CIDWAN UBERLÂNDIA LTDA ME</procurador>
 </revista> ```
````

The Highlighted areas is the data I want to get

[image: The Highlighted areas are the data I want to get]

So, Here's my code:

```
xtree = et.parse("/content/drive/My Drive/data/INPI/RM2558.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()df_cols = ['Processo', 'Despacho', 'Titular', 'Marca', 'Procurador']
rows =[]
for node in xroot:
  processo = node.attrib.get('numero')
  despacho = node.find('despachos')
  titular = node.find('titulares')
  marca = node.find('nome')
  procurador = node.find('procurador')

  rows.append({'Processo':processo, 'Despacho':despacho, 'Titular':titular, 'Marca':marca,'Procurador':procurador})

rpi_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns= df_cols)
```

The head() command give me this:

```
     Processo   Despacho    Titular     Marca   Procurador
0   909359539   [[]]      [[]]         None           []
1   826455069   [[]]      [[]]         None           []
2   916823270   [[]]      [[]]         None           []
3   916625303   [[]]      [[]]         None           []
4   916626873   [[]]      [[]]         None           None
```

The "Processo" is working fine, but "Despacho", "Titular" and "Procurador" are giving me this brackets, and "Marca" is not getting me the data, is all Null values.

I converted everything to strings to see what those brackets would become and got this

```
Processo    Despacho    Titular     Marca   Procurador
0   909359539   <Element 'despachos' at 0x7fb47f082b38>     <Element 'titulares' at 0x7fb47f08e1d8>     None    <Element 'procurador' at 0x7fb47f08e548>
1   826455069   <Element 'despachos' at 0x7fb47f08e5e8>     <Element 'titulares' at 0x7fb47f08e688>     None    <Element 'procurador' at 0x7fb47f08e9f8>
2   916823270   <Element 'despachos' at 0x7fb47f08ea98>     <Element 'titulares' at 0x7fb47f08eb38>     None    <Element 'procurador' at 0x7fb47f08eea8>
3   916625303   <Element 'despachos' at 0x7fb47f08ef48>     <Element 'titulares' at 0x7fb47f099048>     None    <Element 'procurador' at 0x7fb47f0994a8>
4   916626873   <Element 'despachos' at 0x7fb47f099548>     <Element 'titulares' at 0x7fb47f0995e8>     None    None
```

So I guess this are addresses of the data in xml file, is that right?

My next try was this:

```
df_cols = ['Processo', 'Despacho', 'Titular', 'Marca', 'Procurador']
rows =[]
for node in xroot:
  processo = node.attrib.get('numero')
  despacho = node.find('despachos').text if node.find('despachos') is not None else None
  titular = node.find('titulares').text if node.find('titulares') is not None else None
  marca = node.find('marca').text if node.find('marca') is not None else None
  procurador = node.find('procurador').text if node.find('procurador') is not None else None

  rows.append({'Processo':processo, 'Despacho':despacho, 'Titular':titular, 'Marca':marca, 'Procurador':procurador})

rpi_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns= df_cols)
```

And I got this

```
Processo       Despacho     Titular     Marca   Procurador
0   909359539   \n           \n         \n     Vaz e Dias Advogados & Associados
1   826455069   \n           \n         \n     CIDWAN UBERLÂNDIA LTDA ME
2   916823270   \n           \n         \n     Wettor - Bureau de Apoio Empresarial S/S Ltda. ME
3   916625303   \n           \n         \n     Lilian de Melo Silveira Advogados Associados S/C
4   916626873   \n           \n         \n     None
```

Now "Procurador" is also working" and I'm getting some data in "Marca", but what's up with "/n"? Nowhere in the xml file there's a string like this. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: you forgot to close a section `processo` before the ending `revista`

The problem is you didn't adapt the code to the structure of the xml file.

You get a `\n` because `node.find('despachos').text` gives you the text contained in `despachos`. Yet, there is no *real* text in it, just `\n` followed by spaces. Pandas will display that as it is, without any parsing. You have to apply `node.find('despachos').text.rstrip()` to avoid that.

Furthermore, in `despachos`, you have one child node called `despacho`, which is a closed tag so again there is not text. It has however two attributes `codigo` and `nome` that you could use as for `processo`. For example:

```
node.find('despachos').find('despacho').attrib.get('nome')
```

It finds the first node `despacho` within the first node `despachos` and then it extracts the attribute `nome`.

I assumed you wanted something like that:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

xtree = et.parse("test.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()
df_cols = ['Processo', 'Despacho', 'Titular', 'Marca', 'Procurador']
rows = []
for node in xroot:
    processo = node.attrib.get('numero')
    despacho = node.find('despachos').find('despacho').attrib.get('nome')
    titular = node.find('titulares').find('titular').attrib.get('nome-razao-social')
    marca = node.find('marca').find('nome').text
    procurador = node.find('procurador').text
    rows.append({'Processo':processo, 'Despacho':despacho, 'Titular':titular, 'Marca':marca, 'Procurador':procurador})

pd.DataFrame(rows, columns= df_cols)
```

```
    Processo    Despacho    Titular Marca   Procurador
0   909359539   Concessão de registro   DISTRIBUIDORA DE SUPERGELADOS REGIONAIS LTDA    DSR DISTRIBUIDORA DE SUPERGELADOS REGIONAIS Vaz e Dias Advogados & Associados
1   826455069   Concessão de registro   ESCOLA CASINHA BRANCA DE UBERLÂNDIA LTDA-ME CASINHA BRANCA  CIDWAN UBERLÂNDIA LTDA ME
```